# PhoneGap, Jquery List when clicked I need to run some javascript

Tags: jquery, listview, cordova, onclick

I have a phonegap app setup which has several "page" elements. What I'd like to do is when a user clicks a link from a ListView to load the content into one of my "pages" called "fullview"

Currently I'm building the listview from a JSON request, which then updates the "a href" tag

```
   $.each(json.posts, function(i,item){
        $('#news_link').attr("href",item.link)
    });
```

Whats the best way to do this? Insted of updating the a href tag, I'd like to call some JS would would then load the content of the link into the internal page called "fullview"

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call your script on click function using jquery ,

```
$(function(){
      $('#yourelement').click(function (){
                // your code goes here
      })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've managed to get it working using the below<br /> $('#news_link').on('click', function(){ LoadFullArticle(item.rowid); });